# Fitting multiple normal distributions to sample data

Tags: normal-distribution, fitting, mixture-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have a data set of *(time, action)*-tuples. Actions are typically performed at approximately the same times every day, and depending on what the action is it may be done multiple times per day.

If I plot the data for a specific action, it looks like a few overlapping normal distributions with different variances and means.

What I want to do is fit a couple of normal distributions to the data for each action and get their means and variances as output.

My first idea was to use some kind of clustering algorithm and then fitting normal distributions to each cluster, but I am curious if there might be a better method to accomplish this.

Comment: You seem to be looking for [mixture models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model).